# Create a bordered label in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I need to create a custom label in WPF, with borders like this

[image]

So I created a new custom control `TextPlaceholder`, that inherits `System.Windows.Controls.Label`

Now, how to do a border like in the image to that control?
I could use a template in the container's resources

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="InfoLabel"
           TargetType="{x:Type TextPlaceholder}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextPlaceholder}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                            ??????? >
```

but I want having a control that by itself be like this, without a need to add something additional in its container...

Comment: can't you just define it in `\Themes\Generic.xaml`? (setting `x:Key="{x:Type TextPlaceholder}"`). that should basically apply it everywhere

Comment: maybe, but I'd like to manage each TextPlaceholder's corners individually...

Comment: Create a new user control that allows you to modify the display of the corners using properties. Use the control wherever you need it and set the properties accordingly.

Comment: First of all, the code in the question does not give me the corners I want, secondly, I would like to inherit the control. How, for inheritance, I need to have my conrers in the inherited control.

Comment: @Bernard: Should I really create a UserControl, not a CustomControl? How I do to create then corners?

Comment: @serhio: I would use `UserControl`.

Answer (score 0):

Put a Grid with nine Border elements underneath a TextBlock. Work backwards to find the center row and column widths.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Width="######"/>
      <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>... Similar to Rows ...</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1 1 0 0"/>
   ... etc ...
   <TextBlock Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="My Label" />
</Grid>
```

You could even do rounded corners, or whatever you wanted this way.

Of course, you could also make a Path and just do drawing primitives that way.

Comment: I did something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607579/custom-border-in-a-wpf-label   but not sure is I did correctly.

Comment: Looks like you eventually settled on drawing in the code-behind. Normally I'd put it in the XAML as a set of Path objects so you can design all the visuals at the same time. Hope it helped at any rate.