# Custom Border in a WPF Label

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, custom-controls, paintcomponent

I need to build a custom WPF Control something like this
[image]

As I am new in WPF, I used the following code (sorry for VB.NET)

```
Public Class TextPlaceholder
  Inherits System.Windows.Controls.Label

  Const CustomBorderWidth As Integer = 2

  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    Me.BorderBrush = SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush
  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Sub OnRender(drawingContext As System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext)
    MyBase.OnRender(drawingContext)

    Dim pointTopLeft As New Point(-1, -1)
    Dim pointTopRight As New Point(Me.ActualWidth, -1)
    Dim pointBottomLeft As New Point(-1, Me.ActualHeight)
    Dim pointBottomRight As New Point(Me.ActualWidth, Me.ActualHeight)

    Dim myPen As New Pen(Me.BorderBrush, CustomBorderWidth)
    drawingContext.DrawLine(myPen, pointTopLeft, New Point(pointTopLeft.X + 5, pointTopLeft.Y))
    drawingContext.DrawLine(myPen, pointTopLeft, New Point(pointTopLeft.X, pointTopLeft.Y + 5))

    drawingContext.DrawLine(myPen, pointTopRight, New Point(pointTopRight.X - 5, pointTopRight.Y))
    drawingContext.DrawLine(myPen, pointTopRight, New Point(pointTopRight.X, pointTopRight.Y + 5))

    drawingContext.DrawLine(myPen, pointBottomLeft, New Point(pointBottomLeft.X + 5, pointBottomLeft.Y))
    drawingContext.DrawLine(myPen, pointBottomLeft, New Point(pointBottomLeft.X, pointBottomLeft.Y - 5))

    drawingContext.DrawLine(myPen, pointBottomRight, New Point(pointBottomRight.X - 5, pointBottomRight.Y))
    drawingContext.DrawLine(myPen, pointBottomRight, New Point(pointBottomRight.X, pointBottomRight.Y - 5))
  End Sub

End Class
```

Now

1) Is it the best way to do it, considering that I will inherit that control and need the same border on the inherited controls
2) Is it good to specify the default value for the BorderBrush (to be non-transparent), like I did?
3) Why my corners are moved with a pixel (not really right linked)?

Answer (score 2):

A better thing to do is instead of using the `Border` class/control create your own `Decorator` class (that's essentially what a `Border` is).

Comment: what about **inheritance** of this control? Border and Decorator are not inherited... and also, I don't know how to set a border in whitch but corners be visible;

Comment: If you look at the source code for Border.cs, then you'll see that it overrides the  `ArrangeOverride`, `MeasureOverride`, and `OnRender` methods which are key to creating your own type of `Decorator`.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at answering your questions:

- I suppose your solution is ok. As an alternative, you could create a control template, which would add the border around any control you put inside. I suppose you wouldn't have to write more user controls for any control with the border, but just put any control you want inside your template. You can find a sample tutorial about it here and verify it it fits your needs: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-custom-control-templates.
- I suppose it's ok, but I'll look for some information about it
- In order to change the corners you can change value of `myPen.LineJoin` property to `PenLineJoin.Round`. More information about property can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.penlinejoin.aspx.

**Update:**
Answers to your comment:

a) to create border visible only on corners you could try to use a simple border with opacity mask (haven't tested this yet though)

b) I suppose the method you used is ok in your case, (however, if you made a templated control this won't be an issue ;)).

c) Sorry, my mistake. You can try to set `StartLineCap` and `EndLineCap` to `PenLineCap.Round` or `PenLineCap.Square` value. More information can be found on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pen.aspx

Comment: Lucas, thanks for your answers. a) I don't know how to set a border in whitch but corners be visible; b) -; c) as I understand, LineJoin is used in poligonal lines, but I draw 8 independent lines...*

Comment: No problem, I hope my answer is helpful for you. I've updated it to contain aswers to your comment.